# Nested parentheses get string one by one

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have textbox and user write a formula and I get the text  from textbox to split the parentheses .By the way I'm not trying to calculate formula I try to just get strings .I'm trying to get strings from nested parentheses Here is my code:

```
var txt = "((a-b)/month)/(c+d)";
var reg = /^\((.+)\)$/;
var newTxt = txt.split('(');
for (var i = 1; i < newTxt.length; i++) {
    var value = newTxt[i].split(')')[0];

    if (value == "") {
        value = txt.match(reg)[1];
    }
    console.log(value);
}
```

And my output is

```
   (a-b)/month)/(c+d
    a-b
    c+d
```

But I'm trying to get string between parentheses like

```
(a-b)/month
a-b
c+d
```

Comment: I'd consider using an expression parser instead, much easier in the long run.

Comment: I mean nested parentheses ( (..)....). Consider a string like this ((a+b)/c) and the the first string is (a+b)/c the second one is (a+b)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is another way

```
    var a = [], r = [];
    var txt = "(((a-b)+(f-g))/month)/(c+d)";
    for(var i=0; i < txt.length; i++){
        if(txt.charAt(i) == '('){
            a.push(i);
        }
        if(txt.charAt(i) == ')'){
            r.push(txt.substring(a.pop()+1,i));
        }
    }    
    alert(r);
```

Comment: thats what im talking about. Thanks @Sujith

Answer (score 2):

This will capture the text in the outer parentheses, including the parentheses themselves:

```
(\((?>[^()]+|(?1))*\))
```

Output:

```
((a-b)/month)
(c+d)
```

Explanation:

- `(` start first capturing group
- `\(` opening parenthesis
- `(?>` look behind to check that...
- `[^()]+` ... there are no parentheses ...
- `|` ... or that...
- `(?1)` ... there is a nested group that has already been captured by this expression (recursion)
- `\)` closing parenthesis
- `)` end of capturing group

Ah. Sorry. Your question is about JavaScript and JavaScript doesn't support look-behind.